# Can I make a macro in n++ that does a search/replace?

Tags: macros, notepad++

I'm new to n++, but I have been most impressed with this tool so far. I've been trying to record a macro that do a search/replace, but the 'search' part seems to have the initial search text from the recording 'hard-coded' in the macro.

What I want is:

Manually locate the cursor at the beginning of the first line of a fixed format code segment, then Macro actions:

1. move cursor two lines down
2. move cursor right x characters
3. mark charters from pos x to x+n
4. search and replace all occurrences of the selected text with "{p_'selected text'}"

In an more advanced version, I'd like to add some logic to step 4: only execute the replace part if the # of occurrences are > 1 (e.g. by first adding a count statement, but I'm not sure how to obtain the returned count # from the dialog box)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

While I'm a big fan of Notepad++, this sounds like something I would accomplish with [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com). You would select the text and copy it to the clipboard. AutoHotKey would read the clipboard, replace the text as you desire, and either replace the clipboard contents, or send it back to your document. Let me know if you would like to go that route.